# VB.Net Generic Restriction

Tags: vb.net, generics

Ok i am having some issues designing a base-class to handle generics.  Caveat is i need to restrict the type put in as a Numeric type, specifically Int16, Int32, or Int64 (Short or Long).

I know you can do `Of T as {Structure}` but i dont want to allow non-whole numbers as the type.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can think of is to make a `Friend` generic class and build 6 classes inheriting from it.  The `Friend` makes the member private, except to the containing project.  This prevents anything outside the project from instantising it as `IntXClass(Of Double)` for example.

```
Friend Class IntXClass(Of T As Structure)
    ' TODO: Define all IntXClass members.
End Class

Public Class Int16Class
    Inherits IntXClass(Of Int16)
End Class

Public Class Int32Class
    Inherits IntXClass(Of Int32)
End Class

Public Class Int64Class
    Inherits IntXClass(Of Int64)
End Class

Public Class UInt16Class
    Inherits IntXClass(Of UInt16)
End Class

Public Class UInt32Class
    Inherits IntXClass(Of UInt32)
End Class

Public Class UInt64Class
    Inherits IntXClass(Of UInt64)
End Class
```

Comment: yeah thought about that but looking to have 1 base class that takes in a whole positive number that would assign a size to an array.  I have a couple preset derived classes that will inherit this base class but also could be used as a generic class with end-user customizability.  Similar to SQL's Numeric(P, S) type.  All the other numeric types are really nothing more than a variation of the Numeric type.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  How does this fail to achieve having "1 base class that takes in a whole positive number that would assign a size to an array"?  That's just part of the constructor isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

.Net really has no useful support for generics over numeric types, with or without constraints.  [This library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) might help with the implementation aspect of it, but you're still out of luck in terms of defining the constraints.

If you're really desperate to constrain it, you can check the type parameter in a static constructor and throw if it's unacceptable, which should result in a `TypeLoadException` for whoever's trying to instantiate incorrectly.

Comment: so how would i do a compare?

What if i let the parameter be of `Type` and then do something like `param is GetType(Int16)`?  

Seems kinda wierd as if i pass the param as `Object` then i have to do `TypeOf(param) Is Int16`.

What would be the pro/con's of passing the value as Object vs Type?